# How do I install a brother mfc5895cw printer filter for ubuntu 11.10 64 bit?

Tags: linux, printing, ubuntu-11.10

I have already installed the pinter ppd file from a brother download, the system recognizes my printer but when I try to print it says it cannot because a printer filter is missing

Comment: Did you install this deb? http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-5895CW Get the 'cupswrapper driver' from there.

Comment: already did- when I installed it, it was saying that it was the 'wrong architecture' i386- i have installed ia-32 libs and other 32 bit libraries, but that seems to do nothing.